# Writing alternate flows in use cases

Tags: use-case

I am in a new work environment where I see analysts write use cases in the following manners

Manner 1

```
Use Case 1
basic flow
1. task A
2. task B
3. task C
4. task D

Alternate Flow 1
1. task A
2. task B
3. task E
4. task F

Alternate Flow 2
1. task A
2. task B
3. task G
4. task H

* Certain steps (e.g. 1 and 2) are repeated in alternate flows
```

Manner 2

```
basic flow
1. task A
2. task B
3. task C
4. task D

Alternate Flows 
1.Use case 2
2.Use case 3

*Refer to other use cases as alternate flows
```

Looking at Cockburn's book, I see that there is always only ONE alternate flow section in each use case.

So it would be like

```
Use Case 1
basic flow
1. task A
2. task B
3. task C
4. task D

Alternate Flow

3a. task E
4a. task F
3b. task G
4b. task H
```

The clarification I seek is

```
1. Would you have multiple alternate flow 'sections' for a single use case?
2. Does it make sense to refer to other use cases as alternate flows?
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose you described, please consider drawing an activity diagram, or draw a BPMN process diagram.

The modeling goals you describe are beyond the scope for a usecase diagram.